# Jinja2 find_undeclared_variables ignores globals?

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to find out which variables of a Jinja2 template are not covered by globals. I load the template source, parse it and feed the result into `meta.find_undeclared_variables`. No matter what is in the global dictionary of the environment I get a full list of variables for the template. How do I make this operation recognize the globals in the environment and in the template and only return the list of variables not covered by them.

The sample below creates an environment, renders the template to show that global variables are indeed read and calls `meta.find_undeclared_variables` to show its result.

```
from jinja2 import Environment, meta, FunctionLoader, PrefixLoader

def load_mapping(name):
    return 'Mapping %s {{version}} {{docid}}' % name

def load_link(name):
    return 'Link %s {{version}} {{docid}}' % name

loader = PrefixLoader({
    'link': FunctionLoader(load_link),
    'map':  FunctionLoader(load_mapping)
})

env = Environment(loader=loader)

globals = {'version': '1.0'}
env.globals.update(globals)

print env.get_template('map/test').render(docid='asdf')

tsrc = env.loader.get_source(env, 'link/test')
parsed = env.parse(tsrc)
print meta.find_undeclared_variables(parsed)
```

The code prints:

```
Mapping test 1.0 asdf
set(['version', 'docid'])
```

With `version` being a global I would like to change my code so that only `docid` is returned.

I use Python 2.7.6 and Jinja 2.7.3.

Answer (score 3):

```
jinja_globals = env.globals.keys()
print meta.find_undeclared_variables(parsed) - set(jinja_globals)
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like that, considering it just a workaround though. I was looking though for a solution in Jinja. Doing the operation outside the library implies knowledge about its internals and may eventually break.

Comment: Undeclared variables are all variables you have to provide using a template context or globals. When you use {% set .. %} you can declare a variable in a template.  More info in the well document high level API: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/  class jinja2.Environment